# corona drag and drop an object on container or reference

Tags: coronasdk

I am developing a game and one level is solving a jumbled up word. The letters are images like tiles and I am trying to either click a letter and this will move to the first of the allocated spots to solve the word or to actually drag the tile to the spot. Can anyone help me implement this?

Comment: would you care to post some sample code you are trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To drag an object see this tutorial:

http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2011/09/24/tutorial-how-to-drag-objects/

If you just want to tap them and have them move to where you want them, then something like this might work for you:

```
local function moveTile(event)
     -- put your code here to move the tile
     -- figure out the X, Y where the tile needs to move to
     -- either just set the X, Y on the tile or use a transition.to() call
     -- to animate it.
     local thisTile = event.target
     thisTile.x = destinationX -- you have to figure out what destinationX is.
     thisTile.y = destinationY -- figure this out too
     return true
end
```

Then on each tile after you create it, simply add this line to make it tappable:

```
tile:addEventListener("tap", moveTile)
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, this works for well for me, I think I will use this instead of dragging.